# Worklight 6.2 and camera iOS error in autorelease

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, ibm-mobilefirst

but I believe that I'm doing something wrong. 
I'm using the 6.2 wolklight, trying to operate the camera in the iPhone 5, but when I make the build in Xcode 5, it returns me an error:

CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:706:66: error: 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
 UIView* overlayView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds] autorelease];

I'm following the manual to do this Extending Your Business to Mobile Devices with IBM Worklight, 4.8.2 Creating the shell for the bar code scanner.

Note: In android is working perfectly.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `CDVBarcodeScanner.mm` is not using ARC ([Automatic Reference Counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting)) which is a feature that Xcode projects created with Worklight v6.2 use to manage object references in memory. Previous versions of Worklight did not take advantage of this feature.

There are ways to run code that doesn't use ARC by relying on things like [autorelease](http://iosguy.com/2010/09/04/understanding-memory-management/). You can find information [here](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/how-to-include-non-arc-file-in-your-arc-project/) about including a non ARC file in your ARC project.

Alternatively, it seems like the latest version of `CDVBarcodeScanner.mm` I found doesn't seem use `autorelease` anywhere. You can view the latest source code I found [here](https://github.com/jonathannaguin/BarcodeScanner/blob/master/src/ios/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm). You may want to consider updating to a more recent version of [the plugin](https://github.com/jonathannaguin/BarcodeScanner). Keep in mind that Worklight v6.2 doesn't support installing plugins like Cordova v3.0 (i.e. `cordova plugin add <path_download_plugin>`).

I have not used that plugin, so take what I said with a grain of salt. Hope it helps.

Comment: Without changing the sources of the plugin, was only added the flag '-fno-objc-arc' to compile the source CDVBarcodeScanner.mm and it worked perfectly. Thank you